# jQuery getting text-shadow variabile (multiple shadows)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, css

I want to get all shadows applied to an element.

```
box-shadow:10px 0px 10px rgba(1, 2, 1, .5),0px 10px 10px rgba(1, 1, 1, .5);
```

I need to get it into variables :
Shadow1 = "10px 0px 10px rgba(1, 1, 1, .5)"
Shadow2 = "10px 0px 10px rgba(1, 1, 1, .5)"

Also, the color can be in any format : rgb(), rgba() or #...so it can be something like this

```
box-shadow:10px 0px 10px rgb(1, 1, 1, .5),0px 10px 10px #222,0px 10px 10px rgba(1, 1, 1, .5);
```

I don't need the internal values of the shadows, just separate strings of each shadow.

```
Shadows = 
{
   shadow1 : "10px 0px 10px rgb(1, 40, 1, .5)",
   shadow2 : "0px 10px 10px #222",
   shadow3 : "0px 10px 10px rgba(1, 1, 1, .5)"
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to seperate the shadows in classes.

Comment: I am trying to parse a user given HTML which has multiple shadows over an element. I need to store all the shadows for some processing in an array as Shadow1, Shadow2.... etc.

Comment: Maybe something like this http://jsfiddle.net/PY7m4/ - split as needed, maybe they are all the same color?

Comment: Seems they are not the same color in your example, looks like you have to regex then

Comment: The problem with this is, the format of the shadows depends on the browser so rgb can be in front or at the end. Also, the colors can be in hex...

Comment: Any suggestions for the regex?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not that into regex, but I would suggest opening a new question with regex tag, now you have the string at hand, should get an answer quickly